# JMS training in Europe in English or Russian

Tags: jms

Plese, advise a place in Europe where I can be trained JMS in English (Russian also is acceptable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does JMS mean "Java Message Service" to you?

I doubt that there's a course devoted solely to that topic.  It's more likely to be part of a larger Java EE class given for one of the app server vendors (JBOSS, WebLogic, WebSphere, Glassfish, etc.)

You could also look into ActiveMQ instruction from a vendor like Spring.

I'd be surprised if the general information available on-line was insufficient.  The details of configuration are usually app server specific.